# How to reset a timeout in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout

I've been struggling for a long time now when working with timeouts and event listeners in parallel, in react. I'm having issues resetting and removing them in a correct way from the dom on unmount or timeout end.

**I've created a sandbox to make this complicated issue easier to understand.**

When clicking on one of the emails or phone numbers it shows a pop up which should be shown for 3 seconds and then removed. When clicking earlier than 3 seconds on another entry I want the earlier pop-up to be replaced by the new one, so every event listener and so on should be removed. But sometimes it's not working and only showing up for one second as the new state value uses the old timeout.
Also, I want to animate it when removing it from the dom. So letting it fade out after the three seconds.

I've isolated the logic into the `useClickPasteTextToClipboard` hook.

Sandbox-Link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-tree-c37374?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: What you're trying to accomplish requires a higher level of control. A popup that gets triggered doesn't know about any subsequent popups with your implementation, so the timeout just fires with its pre-set delay. If you only want one popup at a time you should implement this via state in your parent component.

Comment: I brought it to the highest level and made a custom hook so all child components are sourcing the state from the highest parent. I don't know what else you mean?